# How to save the notes in local storage in sencha touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, local-storage

I have followed the tutorial  : http://miamicoder.com/2011/writing-a-sencha-touch-application-part-3/

to add and save notes. But save note is not working for me. What is the issue??

My code to save :

```
 NotesApp.views.noteEditorTopToolbar = new Ext.Toolbar({  
           title: 'Edit Note', 
            items: [

                 { xtype: 'spacer' },
                 {
                     text: 'Save',  
                     ui: 'action',  
                     handler: function () {  
                         // TODO: Save current note.  

                       var noteEditor = NotesApp.views.noteEditor;

                    var currentNote = noteEditor.getRecord();  

                // Update the note with the values in the form fields.
                noteEditor.updateRecord(currentNote);  

              //var errors = currentNote.validate();
              /*if (!errors.isValid()) {
                currentNote.reject();
                Ext.Msg.alert('Wait!', errors.getByField('title')[0].message, Ext.emptyFn);
                return;
            }*/

               var notesList = NotesApp.views.notesList;  


                 var notesStore = notesList.getStore();  






              if (notesStore.findRecord('id', currentNote.data.id) === null) {  
                 alert('fjghjkh');  
                notesStore.add(currentNote);  
            } else {  
                 alert('fjghjkh');  
                currentNote.setDirty(); 
            }  

            notesStore.sync();
```

notesStore.sort([{ property: 'date', direction: 'DESC'}]);

```
            notesList.refresh();  

            NotesApp.views.viewport.setActiveItem('notesListContainer', {   type: 'slide', direction: 'right' });  

          }
```

thanks
Sneha

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case, the solutaion was to add the config 'autoLoad: true' to my defined store.
Perhaps this answer helps other, who find this question by googling a similar problem.
Regards,
Andreas